# Deriving first integrals of differential equations and vice-versa

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, hamilton-equations

Suppose I am given the system of ODE
\begin{align} 
\dot x = & y\\
\dot y = & -V'(x) \, y
\end{align}
Obviously the function $F(x,y) = y + V(x)$ is a first integral of the system.
Am I allowed to derive the following system?
\begin{align}
\dot x = & \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = 1\\
\dot y = & - \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} = -V'(x)
\end{align} 
Are the two systems equivalent? Obviosuly trajectories are the level set of $F(x,y)$ for both systems. Is it just a matter of parametrization?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are now claiming that $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}=y$ which is not true in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they are not equivalent, but have the same solution curves as long as $y\ne 0$.

It is in general true that $\dot x=f(x)$ and $\dot x=f(x)\phi(x)$ have the same solution curves but different parametrizations on the set $\{\phi(x)\ne 0\}$.

If $x(t)$ solves $\dot x=f(x)$ and $\tau(s)$ is a monotonous differentiable function, then
$$
\frac d{ds}x(τ(s))=f(x(τ(s)))τ'(s)
$$
so that when $τ'(s)=ϕ(x(τ(s)))$ then the reparametrization $z(s)=x(τ(s))$ solves $\dot z=f(z)ϕ(z)$
without leaving the geometric curve traces by $x(t)$.